# Stokes stream function derivation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, flow, vector-fields, potential-flow

I want to know a concrete derivation of 3D [Stokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_stream_function) [stream function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_function).

The statement is, for example in 3D spherical coordinates (with symmetry in rotation about the  $z$-axis), if
$$\nabla \cdot u=0\tag{1}$$
which is
$${1\over r^2}{\partial \over \partial r}(r^2 u_r)+{1\over r \sin\theta}{\partial \over \partial \theta}(\sin\theta u_\theta)=0,\tag{2} $$
then there is a scalar $\psi$ which satisfies
$$u_r={1\over r^2\sin\theta}{\partial \psi\over \partial \theta}, \qquad u_\theta =-{1\over r \sin\theta}{\partial \psi\over \partial r}.\tag{3} $$

It is easy to show that those form satisfies the continuity equation, but i've found it hard to prove that $\psi$ exists and that it is the only solution.

Comment: Since the creeping flow equations are linear, it is the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define functions$^1$
   $$ f(r,\theta)~:=~r^2\sin\theta~u_r(r,\theta)
   \quad\text{and}\quad 
   g(r,\theta)~:=~r\sin\theta~u_{\theta}(r,\theta). \tag{A}$$
2. Next consider the one-form
   $$ \eta ~:=~ f{\rm d}\theta -g{\rm d}r. \tag{B}$$
3. The [incompressible flow/zero divergence condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_stream_function)
   $$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{u}~=~0\tag{C}$$
   is equivalent to
   $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial\theta}~=~0, \tag{D}$$
   which in turn is equivalent to the closedness condition
   $${\rm d}\eta~=~0.\tag{E}$$
4. [Poincare lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms) shows that the one-form
   $$ \eta~=~{\rm d}\psi \tag{F}$$
   is locally an [exact differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential), or equivalently,
   $$ f~=~\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\theta} 
   \quad\text{and}\quad 
   g~=~-\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial r}. \tag{G}$$
   Here $\psi$ is [Stokes stream function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_stream_function). This proves OP's eq. (3).

--

$^1$ A similar trick works for 3D cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for the outline. I think I got everything else but I don't know how to prove 3. I am not familiar with differential forms and I have no idea how to manipulate divergence with differential forms. I have read [this part of the wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#Divergence), but still have no clue.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you for your help!

Comment: So, is it right to understand (3)->(4) with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#Divergence)?